# Is the HAVING clause “useless” in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, having

I’m reading a paper called [Query Optimization Techniques - Tips For Writing
Efficient And Faster SQL Queries](https://www.ijstr.org/final-print/oct2015/Query-Optimization-Techniques-Tips-For-Writing-Efficient-And-Faster-Sql-Queries.pdf).

That document suggests that *the HAVING clause is “useless” in a SELECT statement:*

> Tip #2: Avoid including a HAVING clause in SELECT statements
>
> The HAVING clause is used to filter the rows after all the rows are
> selected and it is used like a filter. **It is quite useless in a SELECT
> statement.** It works by going through the final result table of the
> query parsing out the rows that don’t meet the HAVING condition.
>
> Example:
>
> Original query:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.cust_id,count(s.cust_id)
> FROM SH.sales s
> GROUP BY s.cust_id
> HAVING s.cust_id != '1660' AND s.cust_id != '2';
> ```
>
> Improved query:
>
> ```
> SELECT s.cust_id,count(cust_id)
> FROM SH.sales s
> WHERE s.cust_id != '1660'
> AND s.cust_id !='2'
> GROUP BY s.cust_id;
> ```

Question:

Is that assertion correct? Does the HAVING clause not have a purpose in a SELECT statement?

Comment: It's not useless (in general). Eg: try to find those `cust_id` that have `COUNT(cust_id) > 10`

Comment: The clause is not typically used for what the example in the article uses it. It's like stating that the addition operator is useless because `SELECT 1+1` can be better written as `SELECT 2`.

Comment: The example use case is useless, not a `having` clause. The only way to express the same is by using subquery, which is less readable than `having`. In general, `having` uses aggregation functions in it, not group by columns

Comment: Their advice is misleading. What they are trying to say is: In the `WHERE` clause you filter rows from the tables, in the `HAVING` clause you filter the result rows from an aggregation. So it makes perfect sense to check a count, a sum, etc. in the `HAVING` clause. But if you want to apply a condition on single rows like in the example, you should move the conditions to the `WHERE` clause, so they get applied as early as possible, and the aggreation does only have to be carried out for the remaining rows.

Comment: The article shows the typical issues when trying to use as less sentences as possible to describe a complex topic. The idea behind the description in this article is correct, but since it was not taken sufficient effort to provide an exact description, the article is quite incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it were useless, it wouldn't exist.

> Use the HAVING clause to restrict the groups of returned rows to those groups for which the specified condition is TRUE

Based on your example, you'd use it as e.g.

```
SELECT s.cust_id,count(cust_id)
FROM SH.sales s
WHERE s.cust_id != '1660'
AND s.cust_id !='2'
GROUP BY s.cust_id
HAVING count(cust_id) > 5;       --> here
```

What is its purpose? You can't use `WHERE` along with aggregate functions, e.g. this is invalid:

```
FROM ...
WHERE count(cust_id) > 5    --> this
AND ...
```